# Filter my cards by organization?

Tags: trello

Is there a way to filter all my cards from a single organization?

Perhaps I have to make a second account one for work another for home, and so on..

If you already solve this, any clue are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You might need to carefully name your boards but you do not have to create a second Trello account to get close to what you want.

To *sort* all your cards by organization click your user icon in the top-right corner of the page (to the right of Boards) and select "Cards", they should then be grouped by organization then board.  So far, I have not found a way to *filter* by just one organization.
Your board names are sorted alphabetically so name them accordingly. "AAA - My First Board" and "ZZZ - My Last Board". (optionally) preceding names with "AAA", "ZZZ" or anything forces a sort order no matter the name of the board.

You may not be able to see this in action until you setup your boards into separate organizations.  If so...

First, **create your Organizations**.
  One for work, another for home and any others you may need (Name them however you want).  To do this click your user icon in the top-right corner, select "Organizations..." then "New Organization..."

Second, **create boards** for your organizations.
  Click your icon, then Boards.  Find the organization and click on "New Board".  To assign an existing Board to an organization select Board Options then "Settings..." and "Change Organization...".  Keep in mind that a Board can be just a single project and you can have as many boards as you want, however, a board can only be part of one organization.

Next, **create Cards** for your boards in the normal way.

Now, going to "Cards" will show you all cards grouped by organization then by board.  The organization name should now appear to the right of each board name.